# Allowing two windows from the same APP to move

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm making a VB.net application.  I have a dialog that pops up at some points.  It is set as `TopMost`.  The problem is, when it pops up, you can't move the main form.  How can I make it so it shows and is usable while allowing the main form to continue to be usable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *sounds* like you're calling `ShowDialog()`, but the behaviour you describe *sounds* like you want to call `Show()` instead (of course, this'll mean that you will not get the DialogResult, nor will the calling code block, but this allows the parent window message loop to handle things like moving the window)